# Does Net::BGP lib support ipv6?

Tags: perl, bgp

I'm new to the network domain and perl world.
I am trying to do router anouncement over BGP ipv6. There is a script that uses Net::BGP library for the anouncement made in ipv4, and I want to convert it to support ipv6.
I looked through this library and understood that it only supports ipv4 (not sure).
The reason why I think so is that the domain given when creating the socket in the link below is AF_INET, while for ipv6 the domain should be AF_INET6.

https://metacpan.org/release/SSCHECK/Net-BGP-0.18/source/lib/Net/BGP/Process.pm#L215

Your comments and guidance are very valuable to me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: See also https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::IP

Comment: Here is another project that used Net::BGP with IPV6: http://i4t.swin.edu.au/reports/I4TRL-TR-170606A.pdf

Comment: There is a patch for Net::BGP in the BGP replay tool v0.2 to use IPV6, see [this](https://researchbank.swinburne.edu.au/file/627b88ea-e0d7-477a-9b64-6317fea582f7/1/bahaa_al_musawi_thesis.pdf) thesis. It can be downloaded here: http://caia.swin.edu.au/tools/bgp/brt/downloads.html

Comment: @HåkonHægland thanks yes I have seen that, do you agree with me about that the Net::BGP is for only ipv4.
 I will try to use Io::Socket:Ip in Net::BGP library to make it work through ipv6 .

Comment: @HåkonHægland caia.swin.edu.au/tools/bgp/brt/downloads.html seems perfect. lots of thankss ! looks like it will save me a lot of trouble.